# Is there any standard way to get creation time of file or directory in FreeBSD programatically

Tags: c, posix, freebsd, stat, posix-api

I want to know how to get creation time of path in FreeBSD C API?

for example in Linux we can use [statx](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statx.2.html) since kernel 4.11, or in mac OSX we can use [stat64](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/stat.2.html)

I want to know is there any way like above for FreeBSD? is there any POSIX standard function/syscall for this?

Comment: Does FreeBSD's `man 2 stat` not show you the requested field? What version do you run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSIX's stat functions provide no way to get file creation time. However, FreeBSD has `st_birthtim` field which you can use.

From FreeBSD's [stat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat&sektion=2) syscall:

```
 st_birthtim  Time when the inode was created.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me, but is it only work on hard link file? or do follow soft link to retrieve original inode? (if your answer is yes for second question, is it configurable or not? and is there any way to find creation time of symbolic link file?

Comment: `stat` follows any symlinks and provides info about the original inode. To get info on symlinks, you'd use `lstat` instead.